# Qt5.0.1 static linking in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, static-linking

I build Qt with a following configuration:

```
-platform win32-msvc2012 -no-icu -no-angle -opengl desktop -static -qt-sql-mysql -qt-plugins-mysql -nomake demos -nomake examples
```

and everything went fine. Btw. i also changed in qmake.conf for win32-msvc2012 mkspecs /MD to /MT for static linking (according to some instructions). Now i try to build the most simple application in Visual Studio 2012, using static linking. So i create simple project (this basic one, from Qt Visual Add-in) which is:

```
#include "test.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 QApplication a(argc, argv);
 test w;
 w.show();
 return a.exec();
}
```

(test is just a plain window) and set two things which i remember since i was doing it on Visual Studio 2010:
1) Project properties -> C/C++ -> Code generation -> Runtime library i set to MT
2) Project properties -> General -> Use of MFC i set to Use MFC in a static library

Of cource in Qt project settings i have set my static version of Qt. In this configuration i’m getting so much errors – http://pastebin.com/6ve3pFUh [pastebin.com] All libs (i think that all) were added by Qt Add-in (qtmain.lib Qt5Core.lib Qt5Gui.lib Qt5Widgets.lib). If i set Use of MFC to default value which is Use standard Windows libraries then i’m getting this:

```
1>     Creating library D:\Visual Studio 11\Projects\test\Win32\Release\test.lib and object D:\Visual Studio 11\Projects\test\Win32\Release\test.exp
1>Qt5Core.lib(qeventdispatcher_win.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WSAAsyncSelect@16 referenced in function "private: void __thiscall QEventDispatcherWin32::createInternalHwnd(void)" (?createInternalHwnd@QEventDispatcherWin32@@AAEXXZ)
1>D:\Visual Studio 11\Projects\test\Win32\Release\\test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I totally have no idea what is going on. In Visual Studio 2010 and Qt 4.8 everything works perfectly fine this way. I read something about more external dependencies which i should add but i’m not sure about that. Ohh and by the way – in QtCreator this static linking works great, but it can’t see MySQL plugin, which also is a mystery for me and i need it to my original project.

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: As far as i remember, i had to build my project with QtCreator. In Visual there were some collisions in building which didn't allow to build Qt statically.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Visual Studio 2013 but I noticed the exact same missing link yesterday.

**You need to add a dependency to Ws2_32.lib.**

If you project compile but crashes with a cryptic "windows platform plugin missing" message, you need to add this into one cpp:

```
Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QWindowsIntegrationPlugin);
```

This could add new dependencies.

FYI Those are the dependencies I use for a default Qt project (Some are only necessary with ANGLE):

- winmm.lib
- Ws2_32.lib
- dxguid.lib
- d3d9.lib
- imm32.lib
- qtmaind.lib
- Qt5Cored.lib
- Qt5Guid.lib
- Qt5Widgetsd.lib
- libEGLd.lib
- libGL
- ESv2d.lib
- translator_commond.lib
- preprocessord.lib
- translator_hlsld.lib
- qwindowsd.lib
- Qt5PlatformSupportd.lib
- %(AdditionalDependencies)